# Commerce- Show a base price (MSRP) and a discount (the real price)

Tags: commerce

I have a number of products for which I would like to display the MSRP (with a line through it) and then the discount price (my store's actual price).

**I do not want to actually discount the products; the "discounted" price is the real price in the system.**  Rather, I want to also show the MSRP (to show what a good deal my customers are getting).  This is similar to what Amazon.com does (they always have the original price with a line through it, and next to that is the Amazon.com price).

What is a sane way to do this?  Should I add another field of type *price* to products?  Should I add that field instead to my *product display* content type?  From the perspective of long-term maintenance, I'm not sure how to approach this.

Here's an example from Amazon:

[image: amazon pricing example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Commerce Price Savings Formatter module](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_price_savings_formatter).

> This module is an extension of Drupal Commerce that provides a display
>   formatter for the Commerce Price field which shows the amount of
>   savings when a discount is applied.

[image]